# Reciting of Sukthams

Tags: vedas, vedic-chanting

Can Sukthams be recited after 12 pm? I heard that during pradosha tome purusha suktham can be recited as the pradosha falls between 4:30 to 6 pm, which is an exception.
Ashta sukthams are there. Other sukthams should not be recited after 12 pm. Any mythological evidence?

Comment: Related - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8222/what-are-best-practices-in-chanting-a-mantra

Comment: The question you refer to chanting a mantra. Iasked Ashta sukthams there is a big diference. I ahve quoted chanting purusha suktham during pradisha etc.

Comment: I have listened to purusha suktam recitation in Shiva temple during pradosha. It is recited right after Sri Rudram.